# Routing authorization with angularjs nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am writing nodejs and angularjs application, and I want to create a simple authorization, that only logged-in users are allowed to see some pages.

I read about jwt (json web token) and my user now got the "token",but what should I do now ? all the routing are in the angular routing. How can I validate the routing there?

My nodeJS code :

```
server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/app'));
server.use(bodyParser.json());
```

My angularJS :

```
var app = angular.module('app').config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.when('/main',{
templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
controller: 'MainCtrl'
});
$routeProvider.when('/onlyLogged',{
templateUrl:'/templates/onlyLogged.html',
controller: 'NewCtrl
});
```

I want my server side to identify when the user moves to onlyLogged , and if the user is not authorized to redirect him to 401 page.

thank you !

Comment: you need to write an interceptor which should pass this token to server with each request

Comment: Maybe you should store `JWT` token in `cookie` , `LocalStorage` or `$rootScope`  and you should look for the presence of token and if token is present with the help of `resolve` in `$routeProvider`  you will be able to solve the problem at client side

Answer (score 0):

you would need to pass that token back to the user/client/angular and store it in some service/local storage

and then pass the token to server upon each request...

[this is one such sample implementation](http://beletsky.net/2013/11/simple-authentication-in-angular-dot-js-app.html)

this part of code stores it in cookie store

```
   var success = function (data) {
      var token = data.token;

      api.init(token);

      $cookieStore.put('token', token);
      $location.path('/');
  };
```

this is where you are passing it back with each request

```
angular.module('dashboardApp').factory('api', function ($http, $cookies) {
  return {
      init: function (token) {
          $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Access-Token'] = token || $cookies.token;
      }
  };
```